# How do I scrape specific information in a table with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code so far:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def make_soup(url):

    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup('http://www.lassen.co.nz/pickandgo.php?fyear=q&teama=SAF#hrh')

table = soup.find_all('table')[1]

for record in  table.find_all('tr'):
    for data in record.find_all('td'):
        print(data.text)
```

Currently it prints the contents of the table, looping through all the columns. How can I make it so it can specifically grab a certain column and a certain row? So for example, if I want it to grab row 1 & column 5 (the data there is 41-23    currently), how can it? Can I make it print out that exact data? Thanks.
[here is the webpage](http://www.lassen.co.nz/pickandgo.php?fyear=q&teama=SAF#hrh)

Comment: So what does the `[1]` do at the end of `soup.find_all('table')[1]`

Comment: The [1] indicates to grab the second table on the page. (because there is more than one table on the page)

Comment: so... then, what's wrong with using that indexing on rows and cells?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't look through all of the columns and rows for the datum that you need.

Prepare the `soup` first.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('http://www.lassen.co.nz/pickandgo.php?fyear=q&teama=SAF#hrh').content
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
```

Get all of the tables from the page.

```
>>> tables = soup.findAll('table')
```

You already know that the table you want is *not* the first on the page but the second. Let's give that a name for easy reference.

```
>>> SAF_vs_ALL_table = tables[1]
```

Now let's get its rows.

```
>>> SAF_vs_ALL_rows = SAF_vs_ALL_table.findAll('tr')
```

It's first row is actually a header. We want the second row.

```
>>> SAF_vs_ALL_rows[1].text
'Sat, 26 Aug 2017RC South Africa v Argentina41-235:28-0SaltaA'
```

Then let's get the columns for the second row, and then look at the HTML for the fifth column.

```
>>> columns = SAF_vs_ALL_rows[1].findAll('td')
>>> columns[4]
<td class="cenb">41-23</td>
```

We can see that it's a simple matter to extract the content of the fifth column in the following way.

```
>>> columns[4].text
'41-23'
```

I noticed the question you had in the comment to another answer. You can put this string into a variable for subsequent use:

```
score = columns[4].text
```

You've said you're new to this. Most of us start with BeautifulSoup, and it is best for many tasks. However, you should be aware that there are alternatives. In this case, the best might be scrapy. Having put the HTML for the page in `page` this is all it takes.

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(text=page)
>>> selector.xpath('.//table[1]/tr[2]/td[5]/text()').extract()[0]
'41-23'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, very helpful! The comments you've made are very helpful! Can you care to explain why is lxml better to use here instead of html.parser? Is there a difference? Thanks for the scrapy suggestion, I'll install it and try to use it now. It does look simpler and easier, so I think I'll use it. Thanks a bunch again!

Comment: The pros and cons of the various parsers are outlined in the BeautifulSoup documentation at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ under the header 'Installing a parser'. I don't think there is a uniformly 'better' over all criteria. You're very welcome for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) which allows you to get the index and the data at the same time:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def make_soup(url):

    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup('http://www.lassen.co.nz/pickandgo.php?fyear=q&teama=SAF#hrh')

table = soup.find_all('table')[1]

for row, record in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')):
    for col, data in enumerate(record.find_all('td')):
        if row == 1 and col == 4:
            print(data.text)
```

Note that indices start at `0`, but since you skip the header row, you want to capture the row at index `1`. And for the fifth column, you want index `4`.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. I'm new to Python so for for this newbie question - can I save this data for later use? Like can I define it as some key word and print it out later?